# How to declare a variable and increment inside a for loop for each iteration in Xtemplate

Tags: extjs4.2

I'am using Extjs4.2.2. In my application i am using three loops, after the first loop i want to declare a variable and inside each iteration of second loop i want to increment the value and use the value in a class of a div. I have tried in the following way

```
'<tpl for="this.resources">',
'{% var parentIndex = xindex; %}',
'<tpl for="slots">',
                                '<div class="ext-cal-bg-row resource-slots-allocation tapaswini-'+(parentIndex++)+'" ></div>', // here i want to add the incremented value of parentindex to the class name tapaswini

'</tpl></tpl>',
```

But its giving error to me . Even am unable to access the "parentIndex" value.

Can anybody suggest where I'am missing. Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance
Tapaswini

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

```
'<tpl for="this.resources">',
'{% var parentIndex = xindex; %}',
'<tpl for="slots">',
   '<div class="ext-cal-bg-row resource-slots-allocation tapaswini-{[parentIndex++]} " ></div>', 
'</tpl></tpl>',
```

By this am able to increment the variable

Thanks
Tapaswini